# inserting query result to a table

Tags: php, mysql

i have here

```
 table_A
| Customer ID | moneyspent |
    001             50
    002             30
    003             20
    003             20
    002             30
```

i have seen a query that gets the sum of all moneyspent from table A

`SELECT SUM(moneyspent) FROM table_A`

but i want the results to be inserted in table B's column"totalspent" like this

```
 table_B
| Customer ID | totalspent |
   001           50
   002           60
   003           40
```

help pls.
thanks

Comment: Please be more specific. When and how do you need to insert/update entries of table_B? Do you use a trigger? or do you have php code to do the job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it works I've checked:

```
INSERT INTO table_B (Customer_ID, totalspent) 
(SELECT Customer_ID, sum(moneyspent) FROM table_A group by Customer_ID)
```